# Laravel what is correct way to implement cascade ondelete?

Tags: laravel, database-schema

I am using Laravel and I have a one-to-many relation. Lets say a 1 Parent with many children. I want to delete all the children if the parent is deleted. I an 99,99% sure of the answer however assumption is the mother of all errors so I want to make sure.

I understand that there is a onDelete('cascade') option in the schema builder. I use it like this for the children schema:

```
Schema::table('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('parents')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Does this mean that if a parent is deleted that the associated children are deleted as well or does it mean that if the child is deleted the parent is deleted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that if the parent is deleted, the foreign key will cascade and delete the children too, if the parent doesnt have soft delete in place, in wich case you need to cascade the delete yourself.

Answer (score 3):

by doing as in the following (as you have already typed):

```
Schema::table('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('parents')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

that means whenever the parent is deleted the associated children are deleted as well and not the vice versa meaning that if a child is deleted the parent won't be deleted.